# Closing a question with clear detail

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I recently asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50332274/json-decode-doesnt-work-for-a-valid-string?noredirect=1#comment87681322_50332274)

But it ended up being closed as off-topic.

My question is clearly detailed and showed my problem and my expected output.

The comments to my question were not related on why the problem occurs as they keep asking on my variable naming when those two functions are on different files.

Why are mods so quick to close questions and how do I reopen my question?

Comment: from quickly glancing at the comments on your Q... it seems like for it to be reproduced, we need sugarCRM..... and it was never mentioned anywhere, except in the latest comment. That would definitely explain the current state of your question.

Comment: And to reopen: Editing will put the question in the "reopen" queue, where people can vote to have it reopened, if they deem it's worth it now. Or deceze, who's currently still engaging on your question, might decide to reopen it if they see fit.

Comment: I didn't find it necessary to add sugar tag as I just needed the PHP part and not much of Sugar's function. My guess here is that the additional data are added before it was saved so sugar still isn't a culprit. Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: But that is your guess.... we don't do guesswork here. We go for full on answers. If we're missing parts of what you're doing, the answers will be guesses... and that's not great for us.

Comment: I would disagree on that as we primarily guess here on how to debug a problem. if you check the answers on questions here they always say something along the line of "Try this" now if you're not sure why say "try"?

Comment: Yes. That doesn't change that the question should contain all the related information. if I don't know sugarCRM, and you explain your problem to me, you know what my first guess will be? "There's something broken in the piece you don't show".  Won't be a very helpful guess.... that's why including the CRM part of this would help people take more educated guesses. I could have made that clearer in my previous comment, making the distinction between "guessing because all the info doesn't necessarily show where the answer is" and "guessing because of lacking information"

Comment: This seems to be one of the reasons an MCVE would be helpful, specifically to ensure the problem is actually reproducible, and so guessing wouldn't be required in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

> My question is clearly detailed and showed my problem and my expected output.

If it did, it wouldn't have been closed.

> The comments to my question were not related on why the problem occurs as they keep asking on my variable naming when those two functions are on different files.

If you've already solved your problem, and therefore know that the solution is not related to those areas, you should post your solution as the answer.  If you don't know what the solution is, and are looking for an answer from someone else, then I'd put some weight behind the *three* different users all indicating that your question doesn't have enough information to be answered, and consider the possibility that your question might in fact be missing some needed information.

> Why are mods so quick to close questions

Because leaving unanswerable questions around is problematic.  Closing them saves other users from spending time on questions that aren't answerable, prevents low quality answers from being posted until the question can be improved, and adds a strong incentive for the question author to improve the question, so that it can be reopened.

> and how do I reopen my question?

Add in the missing information that is being requested by the users in comments.

Comment: I know that those comments are unrelated because it just doesn't. It's like saying that two variables with the same datatype and value are not equal to each other because they have a different name. Thank you for your input

Comment: @magicianiam People are telling you that what you have provided doesn't reproduce the problem you've stated.  That means that *something* is missing from your question, else they would have succeeded in reproducing your problem.  The missing piece may not be what they've theorized it might be, but there is still *something* missing.